# Compare string in XSLT with IF condition

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm using a variable in XSLT that comes from JAVA code which i'm assigning to a
variable and comparing it with a string

Below is my sample code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xmlutil="xalan://lang.comt.des" exclude-result-prefixes="xmlutil xalan">        
    <xsl:template match="/">       
        <html>
            <head>
            <title>sample</title></head>
            <body>                
                <xsl:variable name="language">--LANG--</xsl:variable>               
                <xsl:value-of select="$language" />               
                <xsl:if test="$language = 'en'">testing</xsl:if>                
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The value for `--LANG--` is coming from Java code and returns en.
When I print the variable using `<xsl:value-of select="$language" />` it is giving the correct result as `en`.
However, when I use an `IF` condition to compare the string value it is not satisfying the condition. Can someone help me find what is wrong here?

Comment: You'll have to show us the Java code that sets the variable and invokes the XSLT transform.  Also, if the variable is being set externally, you should remove the declaration in the XSLT.

Comment: As far as I understand it if you want to set a variable value from outside of XSLT (e.g. with Java) then you need a top-level `xsl:param`, so make sure you have `<xsl:param name="language"/>` as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`.

Comment: Is it possible that the value passed to the `language` variable actually contains initial or final whitespace, e.g. `"   en"`?

Comment: no there isn't any whitespace

Comment: HOW does the value "come from Java code", and why aren't you using the standard mechanism for passing parameters from Java using xsl:param?

Comment: Using replace all function in java. When it sees --LANG-- it, it gets replaced the substituted string